# Can we convert option[string] to caseclass in scala?

Tags: scala, exception, converters, case-class

When I tried to convert `Some(string)` into a `case class` I am getting an exception.

Ex:

```
val a:option[string]= Some("abc")
case class hello(a:string)
a.get.convertto[hello] => it is showing error
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow for the `Option` being empty so avoid `get` and use `getOrElse`. Then just use the `String` to make the `case class`, like this:

```
val a: Option[String] = Some("abc")
case class hello(a: String)

val cc: hello = hello(a.getOrElse("default"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `convertto` you're looking for is `map()`.

```
case class Hello(a: String)

val a: Option[String] = ??? //might be Some(s), might be None
val result: Option[Hello] = a.map(Hello)
```